# Is there a way to disable auto-run in Fortnite on iOS?

Tags: ios, fortnite-battle-royale

Since the Season 4 update, the auto-run feature can be enabled by holding down and dragging the left movement control.  Personally, this has caused a few accidents, like when I'm trying to silently crawl around and I suddenly break out into a full on sprint... blowing my cover.. and of course becoming someone else's easy kill.

Anyone know if this can be disabled?  I couldn't find it in the settings.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the HUD Layout controls, go to the extra buttons tab then drag the auto-run button into your layout. Now you'll only auto-run if you drag your joystick forwards and then letting go while your finger is on the auto-run button.

Answer (score 1):

you can not auto-run just by pushing the joy stick forward slightly instead of pushing it fully.